# How to combine to 2 query results of only 1 row from unrelated tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
   Table A            Table B
 -------------     -------------
| nameA| numA |   | nameB| numB |
|-------------|   |-------------|
|  A   |   3  |   |  z   |   1  |
|------+------|   |------+------|
|  C   |   9  |   |  w   |   5  |
|------+------|   |------+------|
|  D   |   7  |   |  y   |   3  |
|------+------|   |------+------|
|  B   |   2  |   |  x   |   9  |
|------+------|   |------+------|
```

I want to get the name columns of both tables where the number in the num column is the closest to some number without going over

I can easily create the queries for this independently but I do not know how to join the results.

For example if I want nameA where numA is closest to 5 without going over and nameB where numB is closest to 4 without going over I would have the 2 following queries

```
SELECT nameA FROM TableA WHERE numA < 5 ORDER BY numA LIMIT 1

SELECT nameB FROM TableB WHERE numB < 4 ORDER BY numB LIMIT 1
```

And the resulting table I would want would be

```
 ---------------
| nameA | nameB |
|---------------|
|   A   |   y   |
 ---------------
```

Just to note, TableA has about 100,000 rows and TableB has about 1,000,000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method just prepends `select` to the two queries:

```
select (select a.name
        from a
        where a.numA < 5
        order by a.numA desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) a_name,
       (select b.name
        from b
        where b.numB < 5
        order by b.numB desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) b_name;
```

Or put this in the `FROM` clause and use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from (select a.name
      from a
      where a.numA < 5
      order by a.numA desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) a CROSS JOIN
     (select b.name
      from b
      where b.numB < 5
      order by b.numB desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) b
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for my example but my real use case requires multiple columns from each table (would have included in example but was trying to make it simple). I tried this and got `ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`. If I wanted my result table to be `| NameA | NameB | NumA |`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select nameA, nameB
from TableA, TableB
where numA<5
and numB<4 
order by numA desc, numB desc 
fetch first 1 row only;
```

or if you want to use the newer "join" notation:

```
select nameA, nameB
from TableA
join TableB
on numA<5
where numB<4 
order by numA desc, numB desc 
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Result:

```
nameA  nameB
  a      y
```